# Why can't Result be treated as a Future even though it implements IntoFuture?

Tags: rust

`std::result::Result` implements [`IntoFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html), but the following code doesn't compile:

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.25

use futures::{future::Either, prelude::*, sync::mpsc};

fn example() -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(0);
    let data = Some(1);
    match data {
        Some(d) => Either::A(tx.send(d).and_then(|x| Ok(())).map_err(|e| ())),
        None => Either::B(Ok(()) as Result<(), ()>),
    }
}
```

Full error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::result::Result<(), ()>: futures::Future` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:5:17
  |
5 | fn example() -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<(), ()>`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `futures::future::Either<futures::MapErr<futures::AndThen<futures::sink::Send<futures::sync::mpsc::Sender<{integer}>>, std::result::Result<(), futures::sync::mpsc::SendError<{integer}>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:9:50: 9:60]>, [closure@src/lib.rs:9:70: 9:76]>, std::result::Result<(), ()>>`
  = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

Moreover, [`IntoFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html) doesn't require `Sized`. Why can't `Result<(), ()>` be treated as a `Future` here?

Comment: `IntoFuture` isn't magic. You still have to call the `into_future` function explicitly. In general, Rust is *very* stingy about when it's willing to do implicit conversions, and this is not one of those times.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's indeed the missing piece. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/enum.Either.html) only implements `Future` when both of its children implement `Future` and their types line up:

```
impl<A, B> Future for Either<A, B>
where
    A: Future,
    B: Future<Item = A::Item, Error = A::Error>,
```

`Result` does *not* implement [`Future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.Future.html), so placing a `Result` directly inside of an `Either` will not implement `Future` either.

The [`IntoFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html) trait is orthogonal to `Future`. As its documentation states:

> This trait is very similar to the `IntoIterator` trait and is intended to be used in a very similar fashion.

You can't call `Iterator::map` on a `Vec` (`vec![1, 2, 3].map(...)`), even though `Vec` implements `IntoIterator`, and the same logic applies to `Result` / `Future` / `IntoFuture`.

---

Most of the time, you will want to use [`futures::ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/fn.ok.html):

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.25

use futures::{
    future::{self, Either},
    prelude::*,
    sync::mpsc,
};

fn example() -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    let (tx, _) = mpsc::channel(0);
    let data = Some(1);
    match data {
        Some(d) => Either::A(tx.send(d).map(|_| ()).map_err(|_| ())),
        None => Either::B(future::ok(())),
    }
}
```

You could also choose to call `into_future` directly:

```
Either::B(Ok(()).into_future())
```